# Which method to use when updating state inside React.useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Lets imagine a simple reducer:

```js
const [state, setState] = React.useReducer(myReducer, {})
```

And `myReducer` with one single case (simplified version):

```js
const myReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_STATE': {
      // Code to update here...
    }
  }
}
```

Now, which of the following statements is best suited to update a state - and why:

*NOTE: `payload` = `state`.*

**METHOD 1**

```js
case 'UPDATE_STATE': {
      const updatedState = action.payload

      updatedState.object = true

      return updatedState
    }
```

**METHOD 2**

```js
case 'UPDATE_STATE': {
      const updatedState = action.payload

      updatedState.object= true

      return { ...state, updatedState }
    }
```

**METHOD 3**

```js
case 'UPDATE_STATE': {
      const updatedState = action.payload

      updatedState.object= true

      return { ...state, ...updatedState }
    }
```

**METHOD 4**

```js
case 'UPDATE_STATE': {
      return ({ ...state, object: true })
    }
```

Comment: payload is the same as state? Is it the same object or are different references?

Comment: payload = state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should Use method 4. You are not **mutating** the state here, which is the React way.

```
case 'UPDATE_STATE': {
      return ({ ...state, object: true })
    }
```

Note: Spread operator `...` creates different references up to one level only.

**EDIT:** Based on comments, here is a simple example of how you could be mutating state, even with the simplest of objects if you are not using `...`.

```js
let state = { object : true};
let payload = state;
state.object = false;
console.log(state);
console.log(payload);
```

Even with `...` you might have deeply nested objects. They will have the same problem, unless you want to spread at every level. There are libraries to help you with deep objets like immutable.js.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the 3 other methods doesnt mutate the state either. They are just copies.

Comment: No. Doing this `=` does not guarantee a deep copy. Changes made to one will be reflected in another. Google deep copy object vs shallow. Here is the first link https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects/

Comment: What if the state is simple as it is. No need for a deep copy?

Comment: I have added an edit to the answer. SO already has a lot of answers explaining deep/shallow copy. If you are dealing with deeply nested objects use some library. Otherwise use spread at levels. Please read the link I have sent

Comment: Thank you. It makes good sense. I'll keep this thread open for a while if there should be any discussion regarding this - as I (personally) cannot know if this is actually the right answer or not.